# Эмуляция браузера на nodejs

Tags: node.js, браузер

Как мне зайти на удаленный сайт через сервер на nodejs, ввести в input текст, после чего нажать enter и получить html код результата. Почитал в интернете пишут про phantomjs. Но в phantomjs нет возможности совместить это с socket.io и express. Т.е. мне нужно чтобы у меня работал nodejs сервер с express и socket.io 
и раз в день подключаться к определенному сайту и брал информацию после того как в поле напишет текст и нажмет enter.

Comment: Ну раз не фантом, то селениум. Ну или сделать по-человечески.

Comment: А можно больше подробностей, о каком сайте идет речь? Может быть, можно обойтись обычным запросом, без эмуляции браузера.

Comment: therainycat, Вы были правы, всё намного проще.)) Я увидел ошибку No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' почитал в интернете и стал искать эмуляторы браузера. А как только я сделал post запрос из nodejs сразу всё получилось. Спасибо